# trouble with WHEN NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a switch around the following. I've tried various permutations but I just cant get IS NOT NULL to work.

```
(CASE billing_code WHEN NOT NULL  THEN billing_amount END) AS Billing Amount
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "searched" form of the [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement. Additionally as the column alias contains spaces it needs to be delimited as below.

```
CASE  WHEN billing_code IS NOT NULL  THEN billing_amount END AS [Billing Amount]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below

```
  (Case When billing_code is Not Null then billing_amount End) As "Billing Amount"
```

Comment: Square brackets are better for delimiting object names as they won't fail if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` happens to be `OFF`